# On change submit form but conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select box in a form and change I call the `this.form.submit()` so the form is submitted automatically.
This is very convenient for me, but there is a case that I would not like this to happen.
Is there a way to make this happen conditionally?

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: `if (condition) this.form.submit();`

Comment: @showdev:If a global variable has been set

Comment: @Cratylus - set to what?  Come on dude - you have close to 20K rep - surely you can ask this a bit more clearly?

Comment: @AdamRackis:I am sorry.Has been set and is not undefined.

Comment: @BrunoLM: `onchange=this.form.submit()`

Answer (score 3):

You want to check if a global var has been set?

```
if (typeof(window.globalvar) !== "undefined")
    this.form.submit();
```

On the attribute

```
onchange='if (typeof(window.globalvar) !== "undefined")this.form.submit()'
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBZSH/)

Comment: @Cratylus you just have to put the code in the attribute, I updated the answer and provided an example.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments: the simplest way to check whether a global variable has a certain value is simply

```
if (window.yourVariableName === 'yourValue'){
    //submit your form!
}
```

To check whether a global variable has *any* value

```
if (typeof window.yourVariableName !== 'undefined') {
   //submit your form!
}
```

---

Also, based on your comment, stop using dom level 0 event handlers, ie

```
<select id='yourSelect' onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Your best bet would be to simply do

```
document.getElementById('yourSelectId").onchange = function(){ 
    if (typeof window.yourVariableName !== 'undefined') {
       this.form.submit();
    }
};
```

Comment: My `form.submit` is inside the select attribute

Comment: @Cratylus - then don't do that.  Create a proper event handler for your select.  document.getElementById('yourSelectId").onchange = function(){ /*above code*/ };

Comment: So I can not do this if I have `onchange=this.form.submit()`. Ok. But your snippet in your comment, when is it supposed to run?

Comment: @Cratylus - it would probably work to put it in the attribute, but that's usually frowned upon.  Your code will be much clearer if you move away from dom level 0 handlers.

Comment: The `document.getElementById('yourSelectId").onchange` shouldn't it be inside another function? When is it called?

Comment: @Cratylus - you put that code wherever you want to set up your event handler.  Usually after your dom is ready

Comment: Sorry for the lamen question.But `document.getElementById('yourSelectId").onchange` can only be run inside a javascript function, right? So how do I call this function in the first place when the page is first fetched? The `onchange` served its purpose at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
         var a=global variable

 function VERIFY(){     
        switch (a) {
            case (a==undefined):
                return false
                break;
            case (a!=undefined):
               alert("all ok");
               this.form.submit()
                break;
        }
     }

<select id="id" onchange="VERIFY();"></select>
//
This might help!!!
```